# "Volumes": null after docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having a problem with docker-compose. My `docker-compose.yml` file is the following:

```
version:  '3.7'
services:
  notebook:
    image: mint01:dev
    volumes:
      - ${GIT_ROOT}:/mnt/shared
    secrets:
      - dock_secret
      - file_secret
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    container_name: my_notebook
    command:
      - "jupyter notebook --port=8888 --ip=* --allow-root --no-browser \
        --NotebookApp.contents_manager_class=jupytext.TextFileContentsManager \
        --ContentsManager.default_jupytext_formats=ipynb,py \
        --NotebookApp.notebook_dir=/mnt/shared \
        --NotebookApp.token="
secrets:
  dock_secret:
    external: true
  file_secret:
    file: ./.env
```

The `$GIT_ROOT` environment variable is correctly defined in my system. If I run `docker inspect`, I see in the output `"Volumes":null`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you specify a static path instead of `${GIT_ROOT}`?

Comment: Yes, I tried it but I get the same behavior

Comment: Ok, maybe there's something weird with the container's path `/mnt/shared`. Try binding another path like `/var/www` just to verify that. Any errors? Container still running?

Comment: The cointer path ``/mnt/shared`` appears to be empty....if I try with another path nothing changes